# App works amazing on emulator, lags on new devices and crashes on older ones

Tags: java, android

I made a simple WebView application with a Navigation Drawer, with the way it worked on the emulator, I couldn't be happier, but then I installed on my Galaxy S6, and it really lagged when I opened the Navigation Drawer, on my sister's S5 the app crashed. I am approaching my deadline and I don't know what to do...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private WebView mWebView;

DrawerLayout drawer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cat8Fragment cat8Fragment = new cat8Fragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat8Fragment, cat8Fragment.getTag()).commit();
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/wp-admin/press-this.php");
        }
    });

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());


}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menuRight) {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        else {
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.home22)
    {
        cat9Fragment cat9Fragment = new cat9Fragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat9Fragment, cat9Fragment.getTag()).commit();
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/");
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}





@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     if (id == R.id.cat1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "פעולות ופעילויות גן עד ג'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         cat1Fragment cat1Fragment = new cat1Fragment();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat1Fragment, cat1Fragment.getTag()).commit();
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/%d7%a4%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%95%d7%a4%d7%a2%d7%99%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%99%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%92%d7%9f-%d7%a2%d7%93-%d7%92/");

    } else if (id == R.id.cat2) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "פעולות ופעילויות ד'-ו' ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         cat2Fragment cat2Fragment = new cat2Fragment();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat2Fragment, cat2Fragment.getTag()).commit();
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%93-%D7%95/");


    } else if (id == R.id.cat3) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "פעולות ופעילויות ז'-ט' ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         cat3Fragment cat3Fragment = new cat3Fragment();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat3Fragment, cat3Fragment.getTag()).commit();
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%96-%D7%98/");


    } else if (id == R.id.cat4) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "פעולות ופעילויות י'-ב ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         cat4Fragment cat4Fragment = new cat4Fragment();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat4Fragment, cat4Fragment.getTag()).commit();
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%91/");


     }else if (id == R.id.randact) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "פעולה רנדומלית", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         cat5Fragment cat5Fragment = new cat5Fragment();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat5Fragment, cat5Fragment.getTag()).commit();
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA-2/");


    }else if (id == R.id.gamelib) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "ספריית המשחקים", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         cat6Fragment cat6Fragment = new cat6Fragment();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat6Fragment, cat6Fragment.getTag()).commit();
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D/");

    } else if (id == R.id.pinukim) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "צ'ופרים ופינוקים", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         cat7Fragment cat7Fragment = new cat7Fragment();
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_fragment, cat7Fragment, cat7Fragment.getTag()).commit();
         mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://peulibrary.com/application/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/");
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(300);
                //Here call you fragmentManager
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return true;
}
```

this is my main code, can someone please tell me what is wrong here? 
thank you.

Comment: What did the crash say? Did you manage to see the log

Comment: I see a bunch of WebViews. Why would that crash anything?

Comment: You should really stop repeating so much code and calling `findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);` and `getSupportFragmentManager()` everytime you need them. Just set them in `onCreate` **once**, otherwise you waste CPU cycles